# Apply QML effects on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt, qml

I have a piece of code that create a simple Frameless window with an image and I want to apply some QML effects (DropShadow effect and Gaussian blur) on the frame not the image, how can I achieve that ?

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Frame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, width, height, parent=None):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setFixedSize(width, height)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
        image: url("images/img.jpg") 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;""")

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.offset = event.pos()
        self.pressed = 1

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressed:
            x = event.globalX()
            y = event.globalY()
            x_w = self.offset.x()
            y_w = self.offset.y()
            self.move(x - x_w, y - y_w)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.pressed = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    c = Frame(width=450, height=255)
    c.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I think you will not able to apply graphical effects to the window. From the docs: `Note: It is not supported to let the effect include itself, for instance by setting source to the effect's parent`. But `Window` is always top item

Comment: Thank you, so there is no way to identify for instance a frame or window with an id and then load a qml file referring that id ?

Comment: You can do some trick but anyway, effect can be applied to `QQuickItem` only but no to `Window`

Comment: Ok thank you very much.